# Answers from Radio buttons and checkboxes to mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, radio-button

For a survey app which has a combination of radiobuttons and checkboxes. How do I use PHP to insert the selected values to mysql db using php?
This is the query for fetching the questions from db:

```
while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc())
{

if($row2["subtype"] =="radio")
{
 echo "<input id = \"radio\" class='radio_input' type=\"radio\" name=answergroup[".$row["PK_QUESTION_ID"].
"] value=".$row2["opt_id"].">".$row2["opt_text"]."</input>";

else if($row2["subtype"] =="checkbox")
{
echo "<input id = \"checkbox\" class='radio_input' type=\"checkbox\" name=answergroup[".$row["PK_QUESTION_ID"].
"] value=".$row2["opt_id"].">".$row2["opt_text"]."</input>";

}
}
```

I tried using  $_POST['answergroup'] for fetching the selected options, but in the case of a checkbox, only one option is being fetched even if there are multiple selections made.

Comment: What you getting in print_r($_POST) ?

Answer (score 1):

When you are dealing with multiple `checkboxes` with the same name, in that case the name of `checkboxes` must be an array like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="1">
```

On form submit you can get the values like:

```
$options = $_POST['options'];
```

here `$options` is an array, so use `foreach()` to get its elements.

Comment: The name is an array. The issue I'm facing is when there's a combination of radio buttons and checkboxes...